# alter table modify column in mysql converts values to 0

Tags: mysql

I have a column that is a varchar(128) which is actually an integer.  However, when I do an alter table modify column from varchar to integer, it changes all the values to 0 instead of converting the values from varchar to ints.  Is this the way it's supposed to happen?

Comment: I cannot replicate this finding.

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry.  Your reply confirmed that it shouldn't be the default behavior, so it made me check a bit further, and it looks like my problem is that when the data was imported into the table, instead of it being imported as 764532, it was literally imported as "764532" with the double quotes.  I believe the double quotes are causing the conversion to fail.